# How to parse a single excel row data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, excel, import

I am developing a ruby on rails app and I need to import an excel file for that. I am using spreadsheet gem.
Now my problem is that I can not get a single row data from excel file.

My code is here:

```
 def actual_import(file)
   puts "In the actual_import method"
   spreadsheet= Employee.open_spreadsheet(file)
   header=spreadsheet.row(1)
   (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
     row=Hash[[header,spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
     $send_name=row.to_hash.slice('firstname')
     puts $send_name.to_s       #this prints a weird result,,described below
     puts $send_name.length
     create
   end
 end
```

And my open_spreadsheet method in Employee model is:

```
def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    #when ".csv" then Roo::Csv.new (file.path nil, :ignore)
    when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new (file.path)
    #when ".xlsx" then Excelx.new (file.path, nil, :ignore)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
end
```

Now `$send_name` prints `{"firstname"=>"Abc"}` and when I use `$send_name.length` it gives me 1 . But I need to capture only "Abc".
My excel file contains only one column named as firstname. But I need only the row data in each iteration as string.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use [BatchFactory](https://github.com/jumph4x/batch-factory) gem.
It uses Roo gem under the hood.
BatchFactory can read all excel file rows as array of hashes which is very handy to work with.

```
require 'batch_factory'
factory = BatchFactory.from_file 'filename.xlsx', keys: [:header1, :header2]
factory.rows
```

This will give you

```
[
  { header1: 'value11', header2: 'value12' },
  { header1: 'value21', header2: 'value22' },
  ...
]
```

In your case you can do

```
factory = BatchFactory.from_file 'filename.xlsx', keys: [:firstname]
firstnames = factory.rows.map { |row| row[:firstname] }
```

This will give your an array of all values from `firstname` column.

**UPDATE**
You can even omit `rows` in `factory.rows.map` because BatchFactory implement some `method_missing`, i.e.

```
firstnames = factory.map { |row| row[:firstname] }
```